# Cannot focus input field with mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I try to click into the generated input-field nothing happens.
The input even lost its focus() and the blur()-event is called.
When I move the cursor with the arrow keys, everything is okay.

An example with the error: http://jsbin.com/atinad/edit
You have to click on the blue square.

I've built a menu with links:

```
<div id="lists">  
    <a href="#" id="list1" rel="1" name="Test #1" class="list  active">
        <span class="text">Test #1</span>
        <span  class="delete"></span>
        <span  class="edit"></span>
    </a>  
    <a href="#" id="list2" rel="2" name="Test #2"  class="list">
        <span class="text">Test #2</span>
        <span  class="delete"></span>
        <span  class="edit"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Clicking on the link set it to an active state.

```
function InitializeLists() {
    $('div#lists a').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $('div#lists a').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");

            list.id = $(this).attr("rel");
            list.name = $(this).attr("name");
        });

        $(this).children("span.edit").click(function() {
            list.id = $(this).parent("a").attr("rel");
            list.name = $(this).parent("a").attr("name");
            list.showUpdateNameForm();
        });
        $(this).children("span.delete").click(function() {
            $("#dialog-list-delete").dialog("option", "listid", $(this).parent("a").attr('rel'));
            $("#dialog-list-delete").children('em').html($(this).parent('a').children('span.text').html());
            $("#dialog-list-delete").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

The showUpdateNameForm-function:

```
list.showUpdateNameForm = function() {
    if (list.name != undefined && list.id != undefined && list.id > 0) {
        var listElement = $('a#list' + list.id);
        var listName = unescape(list.name);

        listElement.children("span.text,span.edit").hide();

        var listElementSave = document.createElement("span");
        $(listElementSave).addClass("save");
        listElement.append($(listElementSave));

        var listElementInput = document.createElement("input");
        $(listElementInput).attr("type", "text").attr("maxlength", 30).val(listName);
        listElement.find("span.text").before($(listElementInput));
        $(listElementInput).focus();
    }
};
```

The input field is shown correctly and it contains the name of the list.
But I cannot click on it with my mouse. Nothing happens.

First I thought it's because of the click-event on the `<a>`-Tag. So I removed only this click-event, but the error still occured. I tried some other stupid things, but nothing worked.
I don't understand what the problem is.

Can someone reproduce it or does someone see my mistakes?

Comment: Not sure if there is enough info here to see the problem. Can you edit to show the full code for the span click event? How is it getting the list variable?

Comment: Hi, added the full functions for this events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As zdrsh mentioned, it's a firefox problem.

I could not solve the problem without changing the structure.
Now I'm using `<div>`-Tags instead of `<a>`-Tags and everything is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is in the declaration of the function:

`$('div#lists a#list1').each(function() {` instead of `$('div#lists a').each(function() {`

Comment: each child of $('div#lists') is an link tag with an unique id: #list[X]. I also added the full code of the functions for better understanding.

Comment: it is a firefox problem, it works ok in chrome.. it would be more quick solution to rearrange the elements instead of dealing with the propagation of the click events..